# Conformal boundary and cusp of figure-8 complement

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

As we know the figure-8 ($4_1$) complement can be obtained by quotienting $\mathbb{H}^3$ with an arithmetic Kleinian group, which has index 12 inside $PSL(2,\mathcal{O}_3)$. The resulting complete hyperbolic manifold has a cusp corresponding to the torus boundary.

On the other hand, the "conformal boundary" (boundary at infinity) of $\mathbb{H}^3$ is the sphere at infinity $S^2_{\infty}$. For a Kleinian group $\Gamma$, the hyperbolic manifold $\mathbb{H}^3/\Gamma$ inherits a conformal boundary $\Lambda/\Gamma$, where $\Lambda$ is the domain of discontinuity ($S^2_{\infty}$ with the limit set of $\Gamma$ excluded).

Then **how is the *empty* "conformal boundary" of $4_1$ complement related to its cusp?** (I know that the conformal structure of the torus boundary is called "cusp shape"); i.e., **should both of them correspond to the $z=0$ "end" in Poincare half-space model?** (since the torus boundary results from the truncated vertices on $S^2_{\infty}$ of 2 ideal tetrahedra under developing map upon gluing).

**Update:** the limit set of $\Gamma$ here is the entire $S^2_{\infty}$ (Corollary 11.8 in [Bonahon](https://books.google.com/books?id=F5qIAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=figure%20eight%20knot%20kleinian%20group%20limit%20set&source=bl&ots=jTdmMINns4&sig=Bu4s-zwx0PmfV4qxhDl7JoT68ic&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOvYe57v_aAhVpxlQKHXy6AEEQ6AEIczAJ#v=onepage&q=figure%20eight%20knot%20kleinian%20group%20limit%20set&f=false)), so domain of discontinuity as well as the conformal boundary is $\emptyset$.

**Confusion:** according to section 5 of [Thurston](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/721c/f2a9c02111f01da0d6f24775aa3fd40f19a8.pdf), the *entire* boundary of a Kleinian manifold $(\mathbb{H}^3\cup\Lambda)/\Gamma$ is $\Lambda/\Gamma$, which is empty for $4_1$ complement. Then what is the role of the torus boundary (cusp)?

P.S.: As a physicist, I may not have stated the definition of "conformal boundary" rigorously, but in my mind it is the boundary in the sense of AdS/CFT correspondence (in Euclidean signature, $AdS_3$ is $\mathbb{H}^3$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group of parabolic isometries fixing a point at infinity is isomorphic to ${\mathbb C}$. (Because it acts simply transitively on a horosphere $H$.) The discrete group $\Gamma$ intersects this stabilizer of the parabolic fixed point (i.e., the stabilizer of $H$) in a lattice $\Lambda\subset{\mathbb C}$. The quotient $H/\Lambda={\mathbb C}/\Lambda$ is a torus with a conformal structure.

Comment: Thank you ThiKu! So if I understand correctly, the triangles at truncated vertices of ideal tetrahedra are on the horospherical "plane", and the torus $H/\Gamma$ is the torus boundary of figure-8 complement as well as its conformal boundary. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. The identification of the horosphere with the complex plane is not unique, but only canonical up to conformal automorphims of the plane. This is why you „only“ get a canonical conformal structure. Choosing some identification of the horosphere with the Euclidean plane would give you an Euclidean structure on the torus, but this is not unique.

Comment: Sorry I am confused again. According to Corollary 11.8 in the book "Low-Dimensional Geometry" by Bonahon, the limit set of the Kleinian group $\Gamma_8$ of figure-8 is the entire $S^2_{\infty}$, meaning that the domain of continuity is $\emptyset$, then the conformal boundary should be $\emptyset$ as well, instead of the torus boundary. I am perplexed by this paradox.

Comment: Yes, the conformal structure is not coming from the domain of discontinuity, which is empty.

Comment: I see. Then how does the torus metric behave near the cusp? Does it goes to 0 or blow up? I have the confusion due to the two paragraphs below Eq.(2.7) in [this 3d gravity paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.0155.pdf) by Maloney-Witten, where they mention that this Kleinian manifold has two ends, including the cusp where metric goes to 0.

Comment: If you think of the upper half-space model and, say, $Fix(\Lambda)=\infty$, then the horospheres are $\left\{z=const.\right\}$ and the action of $\Lambda$ has „the same“ fundamental domain for each horosphere, however its metric is $\frac{1}{z^2}g_0$. So the size of the fundamental domain (and hence the quotient torus) goes to zero when $z$ goes to Infinity.

Comment: Ah, I see why I was confused - I used to think that the metric on quotient torus is "large" since vertices of ideal tetrahedra are on $S^2_{\infty}$. So the torus triangulation "retracts" to the interior of Poincare ball under developing map, hence detaching from $S^2_{\infty}$?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the last question. The torus does not develop to the sphere at infinity, but to some horosphere.